# Samsung Galaxy Nexus 4.1.2 Unable to connect to mobile network

Tags: connection-issues, imei, mobile-network

I recently purchased the handset from the US and currently using it in Vodafone (India) . I upgraded the firmware to 4.1.2 it was working fine and then all of a sudden I am not able to connect to any mobile network.

My IMEI number / Baseband version all say unknown

Is there anybody facing the same problem? Any tips to troubleshoot this problem?

Thanks

Comment: Connect the thing to a pc with usb and do `adb logcat` (maybe you need the sdk before).

Comment: Thanks, I am not sure how but after a battery pull and a reset to factory default settings, it seems to be working again!

Comment: Something in your settings probably got messed up. BTW: You might want to add this as answer, so other "searchers" easily see there is a solution.

Answer (score 0):

(Per originator in comments:)

Pulled battery and also did factory reset. All now works.