# Samsung Galaxy Nexus HSPA : Baseband Unkown problem

Tags: samsung-galaxy-nexus

In further continuation to my previous post, 
[Samsung Galaxy Nexus 4.1.2 Unable to connect to mobile network](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/32865/samsung-galaxy-nexus-4-1-2-unable-to-connect-to-mobile-network).

My earlier solution could only make it work for a little more than 10 days and I am back with the same "Baseband Unkown" problem on my Galaxy Nexus. This problem seems to be persistent no matter any version of stock that I revert to. Currently I am on stock YAKJU-4.0.4-IMM76I.

I have now started looking at the radio logs and I see the lines as below. Can somebody please help me understand them and hopefully help me resolve it.

This is really a frustrating experience with my first android device.

```
11-29 11:54:53.734 D/RILJ    (  472): [0004]< RADIO_POWER error: com.android.internal.telephony.CommandException: RADIO_NOT_AVAILABLE

11-29 11:54:53.734 D/RILJ    (  472): [0006]< BASEBAND_VERSION error: com.android.internal.telephony.CommandException: RADIO_NOT_AVAILABLE

11-29 11:54:53.734 D/RILJ    (  472): [0007]< GET_IMEI error:com.android.internal.telephony.CommandException: RADIO_NOT_AVAILABLE

11-29 11:54:53.734 D/RILJ    (  472): [0008]< GET_IMEISV error: com.android.internal.telephony.CommandException: RADIO_NOT_AVAILABLE
```

Thanks

Comment: Custom ROM? Using [Google Search](http://www.google.de/search?q=%22error%3Acom.android.internal.telephony.CommandException%3A+RADIO_NOT_AVAILABLE%22&ie=UTF-8&nfpr=1) for that error message shows up a lot of discussions about that, mostly related to Custom ROMs.

Comment: I tried everything flashing different radios, custom roms like cm-9, odin and now with a clean install using stock. Still facing the same problem....